# What is a good way to create a default scope to downcase a param?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

For example, suppose you always downcase User emails before saving.

To find,

```
User.find_by(email: params[:email].downcase)
```

But I don't want to code downcase every time I find.

Also, I don't want a case insensitive search.

And, it should be composable and work with where as well. For example,

```
User.where(email: params[:email], status:'active')
```

Comment: why don't you want a case insensitive search if you always downcase user emails before saving? (emails are not case sensitive)

Comment: I don't want a case insensitive search because it is already downcase.

Comment: I think you should tell us what you exactly want instead of giving an example with User and email. Maybe there is another way to accomplish what you want

Answer (score 3):

You could define a scope for this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :with_email, lambda { |email| where(email: email.downcase) }
```

And use it like this:

```
User.with_email(params[:email]).where(status: 'active')
```

---

Eventually you could do this:

```
# in User model
def self.normalized_search(search_attrs = {})
  searchable_attributes = [:username, :email, :first_name, :last_name]
  scope = self.scoped
  search_attrs.each do |attr, value|
    next unless searchable_attributes.include?(attr.to_sym)
    next if value.blank?

    scope = scope.where(attr.to_sym => value.to_s.downcase)
  end
  scope
end
```

Then you could use:

```
User.normalized_search({email: 'HeyHo@santa.com', username: 'Santa'})
```

This code is flexible: you can easily add/remove attributes to allow the search on it, you can easily replace the chained `where` (which add an "AND" clause between each) to a manually written SQL query joined with "OR" instead, etc.

---

If you want a default scope applied (almost) every time, using a column's value, you can use `default_scope`:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  default_scope { where(is_admin: false) }
```

And then calling `User.where(something: some_variable)` will exclude the `User` records where `is_admin` is `true`. To ignore the default scope, use `User.unscoped.where(...)`.

More informations about `default_scope`: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Default/ClassMethods.html

Comment: Yes, but I want it to be a default scope.

Comment: What do you mean by a default scope? You will have to pass the argument to the scope each time since `email` is variable ; If you have a static argument, use `default_scope`: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Default/ClassMethods.html

Comment: By default scope, I mean that the query is scoped implicitly: "Use this macro in your model to set a default scope for all operations on the model." You seem to be saying that a default scope is incompatible with scope arguments...?

Comment: Indeed, `default_scope` can not receive an argument. I don't fully understand what you want, can you tell us in your original question what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: The goal is to downcase the search criteria on certain fields because they are always downcased before saving. But a named scope is not a good way to do it. So I guess a find method is the best way...

Comment: Several named scopes could do the trick, or a `search` method can do the trick too. I update my answer, you will see the changes in a minute